# How to use plugin functions inside of child theme template

Tags: php, wordpress

So,

I've been trying to make a template, which runs plugin functions.
Here is template I've tried to make.
And here are the errors I get

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\www\htdocs\FCN-GIT\wp-content\themes\Avada-Child-Theme\single-wpt_test.php on line 39

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method WP::doAction() in C:\www\htdocs\FCN-GIT\wp-content\themes\Avada-Child-Theme\single-wpt_test.php on line 44

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Test
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Avada
* @since 2016
*/
?>

<?php
// Can be overriden in your theme as entry-content-wpt-test-fill-form.php

/* @var $answerIdName string */
/* @var $answerIndex integer */
/* @var $isShowContent boolean */
/* @var $formAttributes array */
/* @var $content string */
/* @var $subTitle string */
/* @var $shortDescription string */
/* @var $test WpTesting_Model_Test */
/* @var $questions WpTesting_Model_Question[] */
/* @var $isFinal boolean */
/* @var $isMultipleAnswers boolean */
/* @var $submitButtonCaption string */
/* @var $stepsCounter string */
/* @var $wp WpTesting_WordPressFacade */
/* @var $hiddens array */
?>
<div class="wpt_test fill_form">

<?php if ($isShowContent): ?>
<div class="content">
    <?php echo $content ?>
</div>
<?php endif ?>

<div class="content"><form
<?php foreach ($formAttributes as $key => $value):?>
    <?php echo $key ?>="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(is_array($value) ? json_encode($value) : $value) ?>"
<?php endforeach ?>>
<?php if ($subTitle): ?><h2 class="subtitle"><?php echo $subTitle ?></h2><?php endif ?>
<?php if ($shortDescription): ?><div class="short-description"><?php echo $wp->autoParagraphise($shortDescription) ?></div><?php endif ?>
<?php $wp->doAction('wp_testing_template_fill_form_questions_before') ?>
<?php foreach($questions as $q => $question): /* @var $question WpTesting_Model_Question */ ?>
    <?php $wp->doAction('wp_testing_template_fill_form_question_before', $question, $q) ?>
    <div class="question">

        <div class="title">
            <span class="number"><?php echo $q+1 ?>.</span><span class="title"><?php echo $question->getTitle() ?>
            <?php $wp->doAction('wp_testing_template_fill_form_label_end', array('required' => true)) ?></span>
        <?php if (!$isMultipleAnswers): ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $answerIdName ?>[<?php echo $answerIndex ?>]" value="" />
        <?php endif ?>
        </div>

    <?php foreach($question->buildAnswers() as $a => $answer): /* @var $answer WpTesting_Model_Answer */ ?>
        <?php $answerId = 'wpt-test-question-' . $question->getId() . '-answer-' . $answer->getId() ?>

        <div class="answer">

            <label for="<?php echo $answerId ?>">
                <input type="<?php echo $isMultipleAnswers ? 'checkbox' : 'radio' ?>" id="<?php echo $answerId ?>"
                    data-errormessage="<?php echo $isMultipleAnswers
                        ? __('Please select at least one answer.', 'wp-testing')
                        : __('Please choose only one answer.', 'wp-testing') ?>"
                    <?php if (0 == $a): ?>required="required" aria-required="true"<?php endif ?>
                    name="<?php echo $answerIdName ?>[<?php echo $answerIndex ?>]" value="<?php echo $answer->getId() ?>" />
                <?php echo $answer->getTitleOnce() ?>
            </label>

        </div>
        <?php if ($isMultipleAnswers) {$answerIndex++;} ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>

    </div>
    <?php $wp->doAction('wp_testing_template_fill_form_question_after', $question, $q) ?>
    <?php if (!$isMultipleAnswers) {$answerIndex++;} ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
<?php $wp->doAction('wp_testing_template_fill_form_questions_after') ?>

<?php if($isFinal): ?>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="<?php echo $submitButtonCaption ?>" />
        <?php if($stepsCounter): ?><span class="steps-counter"><?php echo $stepsCounter ?></span><?php endif ?>
    </p>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="wpt_warning">
        <h4><?php echo __('Test is under construction', 'wp-testing') ?></h4>
        <p><?php echo __('You can not get any results from it yet.', 'wp-testing') ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
<?php foreach($hiddens as $name => $value): ?><input type="hidden" name="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name) ?>" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($value) ?>" /><?php endforeach ?>
</form></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this, but overriding the default template of the plugin, I needed to have two templates which differences in one, so essentially, a template which has code for my homepage and for another page.

The homepage has the changes, and the other page does not, and it uses the default theme template.

Here was my solution to having two templates in one using the plugin code.

```
<?php
// Can be overriden in your theme as entry-content-wpt-test-fill-form.php

/* @var $answerIdName string */
/* @var $answerIndex integer */
/* @var $isShowContent boolean */
/* @var $formAttributes array */
/* @var $content string */
/* @var $subTitle string */
/* @var $shortDescription string */
/* @var $test WpTesting_Model_Test */
/* @var $questions WpTesting_Model_Question[] */
/* @var $isFinal boolean */
/* @var $isMultipleAnswers boolean */
/* @var $submitButtonCaption string */
/* @var $stepsCounter string */
/* @var $wp WpTesting_WordPressFacade */
/* @var $hiddens array */
?>

<?php if (is_front_page()): ?>
  <div class="home-health-insight wpt_test fill_form">

    <div class="answers">
      <div class="content">
        <form
        <?php foreach ($formAttributes as $key => $value):?>
          <?php echo $key ?>="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(is_array($value) ? json_encode($value) : $value) ?>"
        <?php endforeach; ?>>
        <?php if ($isShowContent): ?><div class="content" style="margin:0;"><?php echo $content ?></div><?php endif ?>    
        <?php if ($shortDescription): ?><div class="short-description"><?php echo $wp->autoParagraphise($shortDescription) ?></div><?php endif ?>
        <?php $wp->doAction('wp_testing_template_fill_form_questions_before') ?>
        <div class="question">      
          <div class="question-titles">
            <div class="question-labels">
              <label class="answerlbl"  for="<?php echo $answerId ?>">
                None of the time
              </label>
              <label class="answerlbl" for="<?php echo $answerId ?>">
                Rarely
              </label>
              <label class="answerlbl" for="<?php echo $answerId ?>">
                Some of the time
              </label>
              <label class="answerlbl" for="<?php echo $answerId ?>">
                Often
              </label>
              <label class="answerlbl"  for="<?php echo $answerId ?>">
                All of the time
              </label>      
            </div>  
          </div>                              
          <?php foreach($questions as $q => $question): /* @var $question WpTesting_Model_Question */ ?>
            <?php $wp->doAction('wp_testing_template_fill_form_question_before', $question, $q) ?>

            <div class="title">
              <span class="question-title" style="width:100%;"><?php echo $question->getTitle() ?>
                <?php $wp->doAction('wp_testing_template_fill_form_label_end', array('required' => true)) ?></span>
                <?php if (!$isMultipleAnswers): ?>
                  <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $answerIdName ?>[<?php echo $answerIndex ?>]" value="" />
                <?php endif ?>
              </div>
              <div class="answer-block">
                <?php foreach($question->buildAnswers() as $a => $answer): /* @var $answer WpTesting_Model_Answer */ ?>
                  <?php $answerId = 'wpt-test-question-' . $question->getId() . '-answer-' . $answer->getId() ?>

                  <div class="answer">

                    <input type="<?php echo $isMultipleAnswers ? 'checkbox' : 'radio' ?>" id="<?php echo $answerId ?>"
                    data-errormessage="<?php echo $isMultipleAnswers
                    ? __('Please select at least one answer.', 'wp-testing')
                    : __('Please choose only one answer.', 'wp-testing') ?>"
                    <?php if (0 == $a): ?>required="required" aria-required="true"<?php endif ?>
                    name="<?php echo $answerIdName ?>[<?php echo $answerIndex ?>]" value="<?php echo $answer->getId() ?>" />

                  </div>
                  <?php if ($isMultipleAnswers) {$answerIndex++;} ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
              </div>
              <?php $wp->doAction('wp_testing_template_fill_form_question_after', $question, $q) ?>
              <?php if (!$isMultipleAnswers) {$answerIndex++;} ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
          </div>

          <?php $wp->doAction('wp_testing_template_fill_form_questions_after') ?>

          <?php if($isFinal): ?>
            <p>
              <input type="submit" class="button" value="<?php echo $submitButtonCaption ?>" />
              <?php if($stepsCounter): ?><span class="steps-counter"><?php echo $stepsCounter ?></span><?php endif ?>
            </p>
          <?php else: ?>
            <div class="wpt_warning">
              <h4><?php echo __('Test is under construction', 'wp-testing') ?></h4>
              <p><?php echo __('You can not get any results from it yet.', 'wp-testing') ?></p>
            </div>
          <?php endif ?>
          <?php foreach($hiddens as $name => $value): ?><input type="hidden" name="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name) ?>" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($value) ?>" /><?php endforeach ?>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
<?php else: ?>
  <div class="wpt_test fill_form">

  <?php if ($isShowContent): ?>
  <div class="content">
      <?php echo $content ?>
  </div>
  <?php endif ?>

  <div class="content"><form
  <?php foreach ($formAttributes as $key => $value):?>
      <?php echo $key ?>="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(is_array($value) ? json_encode($value) : $value) ?>"
  <?php endforeach ?>>
  <?php if ($subTitle): ?><h2 class="subtitle"><?php echo $subTitle ?></h2><?php endif ?>
  <?php if ($shortDescription): ?><div class="short-description"><?php echo $wp->autoParagraphise($shortDescription) ?></div><?php endif ?>
  <?php $wp->doAction('wp_testing_template_fill_form_questions_before') ?>
  <?php foreach($questions as $q => $question): /* @var $question WpTesting_Model_Question */ ?>
      <?php $wp->doAction('wp_testing_template_fill_form_question_before', $question, $q) ?>
      <div class="question">

          <div class="title">
              <span class="number"><?php echo $q+1 ?>.</span><span class="title"><?php echo $question->getTitle() ?>
              <?php $wp->doAction('wp_testing_template_fill_form_label_end', array('required' => true)) ?></span>
          <?php if (!$isMultipleAnswers): ?>
              <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $answerIdName ?>[<?php echo $answerIndex ?>]" value="" />
          <?php endif ?>
          </div>

      <?php foreach($question->buildAnswers() as $a => $answer): /* @var $answer WpTesting_Model_Answer */ ?>
          <?php $answerId = 'wpt-test-question-' . $question->getId() . '-answer-' . $answer->getId() ?>

          <div class="answer">

              <label for="<?php echo $answerId ?>">
                  <input type="<?php echo $isMultipleAnswers ? 'checkbox' : 'radio' ?>" id="<?php echo $answerId ?>"
                      data-errormessage="<?php echo $isMultipleAnswers
                          ? __('Please select at least one answer.', 'wp-testing')
                          : __('Please choose only one answer.', 'wp-testing') ?>"
                      <?php if (0 == $a): ?>required="required" aria-required="true"<?php endif ?>
                      name="<?php echo $answerIdName ?>[<?php echo $answerIndex ?>]" value="<?php echo $answer->getId() ?>" />
                  <?php echo $answer->getTitleOnce() ?>
              </label>

          </div>
          <?php if ($isMultipleAnswers) {$answerIndex++;} ?>
      <?php endforeach ?>

      </div>
      <?php $wp->doAction('wp_testing_template_fill_form_question_after', $question, $q) ?>
      <?php if (!$isMultipleAnswers) {$answerIndex++;} ?>
  <?php endforeach ?>
  <?php $wp->doAction('wp_testing_template_fill_form_questions_after') ?>

  <?php if($isFinal): ?>
      <p>
          <input type="submit" class="button" value="<?php echo $submitButtonCaption ?>" />
          <?php if($stepsCounter): ?><span class="steps-counter"><?php echo $stepsCounter ?></span><?php endif ?>
      </p>
  <?php else: ?>
      <div class="wpt_warning">
          <h4><?php echo __('Test is under construction', 'wp-testing') ?></h4>
          <p><?php echo __('You can not get any results from it yet.', 'wp-testing') ?></p>
      </div>
  <?php endif ?>
  <?php foreach($hiddens as $name => $value): ?><input type="hidden" name="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name) ?>" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($value) ?>" /><?php endforeach ?>
  </form></div>

  </div>
<?php endif ?>
```